# Gmail stripping out domain from img src tag

Tags: php, email, gmail

Trying to send a mail from a website using the PHPMailer library.

Every time I send the mail to my Gmail account, Google strips out the URL so instead of it being

```
https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TK-oMxw0ycU1MRJGYpEZ17XpbKPE6YbLSoZh3GFhHXEKq1nLU_rJd0o=s0-d-e1-ft#http://www.myurl.com/img/map.jpg
```

I get

```
https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TK-oMxw0ycU1MRJGYpEZ17XpbKPE6YbLSoZh3GFhHXEKq1nLU_rJd0o=s0-d-e1-ft#http:///img/map.jpg
```

and my images break. How do I get my images to show on Gmail? I tried being sneaky and sending the mail via SMTP using my Gmail credentials to see if that would fix the problem, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried escaping the url? Something like the following might work:

```
https://ci4.googleusercontent.com/proxy/TK-oMxw0ycU1MRJGYpEZ17XpbKPE6YbLSoZh3GFhHXEKq1nLU_rJd0o=s0-d-e1-ft#http%3A%2F%2Fwww.myurl.com%2Fimg%2Fmap.jpg
```

See [this](http://www.december.com/html/spec/esccodes.html) for a small list of possible escape sequences.